# Best way to get HTTP data and handle a 404?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am fairly new to React so I don't know the best ways to get data. I have a page URL like `/country/japan` and this is my component:

```
var Country = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var _this = this,
        country = _this.props.params.country;

    Axios.get('http://URL/?search=' + country)
      .then(function(result) {
        _this.setState({
          country: result.data[0]
        });
      });
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
    var country = this.state.country;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{country.name}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }

});
```

I cannot seem to access the country data. What's the proper way to do this? Also how would you trigger a 404?

Comment: Usually we just use [`.fetch`](https://github.com/github/fetch) but using an AJAX library like Axios is fine. Look at their documentation to find how to handle a request failure. Probably a `.catch` after `.then`.

Answer (score 1):

I would say first understand the difference between presentational and container components.

**Presentational components:**

- Are concerned with how things look.
- May contain both presentational and container components inside, and  usually have some DOM markup  and styles of their own. Often allow containment via this.props.children.
- Have no dependencies on the rest of the app, such as Flux actions or stores.
- Don’t specify how the data is loaded or mutated.
- Receive data and callbacks exclusively via props.
- Rarely have their own state (when they do, it’s UI state rather than
  data).
- Are written as functional components unless they need state,
  lifecycle hooks, or performance optimizations.
- Examples: Page, Sidebar, Story, UserInfo, List.

**Container components:**

- Are concerned with how things work.
- May contain both presentational and container components** inside but
  usually don’t have any DOM markup of their own except for some
  wrapping divs, and never have any styles.
- Provide the data and behavior to presentational or other container
  components.
- Call Flux actions and provide these as callbacks to the
  presentational components.
- Are often stateful, as they tend to serve as data sources.
- Are usually generated using higher order components such as connect()
  from React Redux, createContainer() from Relay, or Container.create()
  from Flux Utils, rather than written by hand.
- Examples: UserPage, FollowersSidebar, StoryContainer,
  FollowedUserList.

You can check more [here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.812fntlyd). This would help you understand how to trigger an api call(it should be in containers).

So now coming to your code. I would say move your api code to the container and call your component inside the container.

```
var CountryContainer = React.createClass({


 componentDidMount: function() {
       var _this = this,
        country = _this.props.params.country;

    axios.get('http://URL/?search=' + country)
      .then(function(result) {
         //200-300 response codes
         //update you state here with say variable data
      .catch(function(error){
          //400+ response codes
        }
      });

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <Country data={this.state.data} />
    );
  }

});
```

I would suggest you go to over axios documentation. They have clearly mention when the API call fails and how to handle it :)